# D3 force layout - How to achieve 3D look of nodes?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, 3d, force-layout

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d24XB/) of `D3` cluster force layout:

[image]

How to achieve 3D look of nodes similar to this picture: *(don't pay attention on diagram itself, this is just illustration of "look" of circles)*

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjsnD/) of the solution. It is based on [SVG radial gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_radial.asp).

---

For each node, a gradient is defined:

```
var grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient")
    .data(nodes)
   .enter()
    .append("radialGradient")
    .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", "100%")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "grad" + i; });

grads.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .style("stop-color", "white");

grads.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .style("stop-color",  function(d) { return color(d.cluster); });
```

Then, instead of line:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.cluster); })
```

this line is added in the code that creates circles:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return "url(#grad" + i + ")";
})
```

This produces this effect:(animated gif that I used has some limitations for number of colors, so gradients are not smooth as in real example)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create linear or radial gradient based on your requirement using different colors. Set fill attribute as gradient.

```
var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
  .append("svg:linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "100%")
    .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#0c0")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#c00")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("fill", "url(#gradient)")
    .call(force.drag);
```